# Can two different natural numbers raised to the same irrational power be integers?

Tags: number-theory, irrational-numbers, transcendental-numbers

Is it possible to find an $\alpha\in\mathbb R$, $\alpha>0$ so that for all $n\in\mathbb N$, $n^\alpha\in\mathbb N$?

A  stronger(restricted) problem: Can $2^\alpha$ and $3^\alpha$ be simultaneously integers?? Here $\alpha >0$.

For the second one, I can only reduce to $\cfrac{\log 3}{\log 2} = \cfrac{\log s}{\log q}$ for integer solution $(s,q)$, and then no idea..... For the first one, we have excluded all $\alpha\in\mathbb Q$(which is easy). I tried to use large enough $n^\alpha\in\mathbb N$ and to show $(n+1)^\alpha$ fails to be an integer but I failed.

I think there is more advanced number theoretic technique to be used.

Comment: Not quite a duplicate, given the stronger question re. $2^\alpha, 3^\alpha.$

Comment: check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Six_exponentials_theorem

Comment: @coffeemath it was evoked, though : "I think considering $n=2,3$ is enough to show a contradiction"...

Answer (score 1):

Let $$\alpha = log _3 7$$
Then

$$ 3^\alpha ,9^\alpha, 27^\alpha, 81^\alpha,.......$$

are all integers.

Comment: This answers the question in the title, but not either of those in the question body.

Comment: Yes, I agree. The  other two questions sound almost  impossible.